# Login with PHP, SQL - Security and Resource Concern

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am currently developing a log in system, and I am at a fundamental crossroad.

I cannot decide between the following two possible ways of doing authentication with regards to security and resource management.

I. Approach

```
$user = $_POST["user"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

$link = new PDO('mysql....', $user, $pass);

$stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT pass FROM userlogin WHERE User= ?;');

$stmt->execute([$user]);
$hashed = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
if($stmt[0]['pass'] === $hashed){
   password_needs_rehash($hashed, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost'=>15]);
   header('Location: .......');
}
```

or

II. Approach

```
$user = $_POST["user"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

$link = new PDO('mysql....', $user, $pass);

$stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT userinfo FROM userlogin WHERE User= ? AND Pass=?;');

$stmt->execute([$user, password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)]);
if(count($stmt[0]) == 1){
   password_needs_rehash($stmt[0]['pass'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost'=>15]);
   header('Location: .......');
}
```

My reasoning is that the second approach is better, because:

- in case that someone manages somehow to penetrate the HTTPS, the verification is done by the database and not by PHP. Therefore, the packet cannot be sniffed.
- reduces processing overhead without having to issue other MySQL statements in order to receive information in case authorization is successful.

Am I correct or am I missing something from a security and processing perspective?

Comment: You should be using `password_verify()` to authenticate, as `password_hash()` is not idempotent. It produces different output every time you call it. I.e., you can't hash the password you're checking now and expect that to match the hash of a password you stored earlier.

Comment: Approach 2 won't work at all, for the reason Alex notes above. I assume you didn't test this before asking the question?

Comment: Also note, `password_needs_rehash()` here accomplishes nothing, as you're just throwing away the return value.

Comment: `in case that someone manages somehow to penetrate the HTTPS, the verification is done by the database and not by php. Therefore, the packet cannot be sniffed`...I don't think any of this makes any sense. If someone "pentrates the HTTPS" as you describe it, they will see the content of the HTTP request going to the server, and what came back again. They still won't see anything that PHP actually does, or any PHP code. And in either of the approaches, they'd see the plain-text password the user submitted. There's nothing you can really do in the server-side code to mitigate against that.

Comment: Both approaches are super bad. Using user input to directly give access to the database is a very bad idea.

Comment: Agreed. You seem to have confused database login with application login. Your PHP _application_ needs _one_ set of mysql credentials, which are stored safely on the server somewhere. PHP can then connect to the _database_ with those details. Meanwhile your users can log into your _application_ using the username and password they have created for that purpose (and which you so happen to store nice and safely inside a database table). Fix that, and employ password_verify, and then aside from that approach 1 is the way to go.

Comment: P.S. Any particular reason you're trying to develop a login system yourself (as, it seems like, someone relatively inexperienced at least in these matters) and aren't using a ready-made and reliable system (such as you can commonly find supplied with PHP frameworks, or as ready-made modules, or from 3rd parties like Microsoft/Google/Apple)? It's quite easy to mess it up very badly and make your system insecure. Unless you have an academic interest in it, I'd say don't try to re-invent the wheel (badly), use an existing solution and move onto adding some real value to your app with new features

Comment: I see the mistake in the user pass, an oversight while writing the rudimentary example. However, this isn't to what I want to draw your attention. Now that I think about it security isn't really a concern.

However, processing power is wouldn't a check against db reduce the number of operations, therefore saving processing power, than retrieving one time data from the the db, verifying the password, then querying the db again at/after redirection.

Comment: You're writing a login system, but security isn't a concern? Doesn't that sound like a bit of a contradiction to you? It certainly does to me.

Comment: No, security isn't a concern with regard to the question. It is a concern overall. However, the essence of the question was. Is it better to query the DB, extract the hash and then match it, or is it better to directly extract data for the user upon login on the condition that the submitted username and password pair to the DB are correct?

Comment: Well you _can't_ verify it in the database, you must use password_verify. So there isn't a choice.

Comment: OK, thanks for your time. While this might have been annoying for you, it was enlightening for me.